# Wireguard Client on Debian 10 on OVH VPS connected but does not pass traffic

Tags: routing, vpn, wireguard

I have simple topology. I want my VPS on OVH to connect to Wireguard VPN Server.
Server config is ok because other client (Windows) work well with it.

VPN Client Wireguard runs on Debian 10:
4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
wireguard-tools v1.0.20210223

vpn clcient config:

```
/etc/wireguard# cat wg1.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.11/24
DNS = 1.1.1.2
PrivateKey = XXXXXXXX

[Peer]
PublicKey = YYYYYYYY
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.1/24
Endpoint = 169.1.1.2:51820 # real ip is masked
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Client WG output:

```
Client # wg
interface: wg1
  public key: YYYYYYYY
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 52855

peer: TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
  endpoint: 169.1.1.2:51820
  allowed ips: 10.10.10.0/24
  latest handshake: 4 seconds ago
  transfer: 92 B received, 180 B sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds

Client # ip route
default via 169.1.1.1 dev eth0 
10.10.10.0/24 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.11 
169.1.1.1 dev eth0 scope link

Client # traceroute 10.10.10.1
traceroute to 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
```

Server config:

```
cat wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

[Peer]
PublicKey = YYYYYYYY
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.11/32

Server: # wg
interface: wg0
  public key: TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: YYYYYYYY
  endpoint: 169.1.1.1:52855
  allowed ips: 10.10.10.11/32
  latest handshake: 36 seconds ago
  transfer: 6.94 KiB received, 7.41 KiB sent
```

What I am doing wrong?
Issue is only with Debian 10 VPS as wireguard client. I can’t ping the Server wg interface even if routing and iptables allow for it. It looks Wireguard work but does not forward the traffic?
What I should check to solve it?

Comment: in client config - change `AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.1/24` to `AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.0/24`

Comment: Thanks but these did not help. Still I can't ping 10.10.10.1 (serwer wg interface) from client. It looks like wg tunnel is established but I can't route the traffic into it.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it.
There was typo in iptables rule instead of wg0 it was wg1 to accept.....
Sorry for bothering and hope these will stay for others.